# Control.Invoke does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, multithreading

> Error: The name 'Invoke' does not exist in the current context

The class I am working on already has a base class so I can't have it implement something like Windows.Forms.Control.

I looked at article [here](http://bit.ly/p5hyFi) but I don't want to implement another interface, and don't know what I would put in the methods.

This is a fairly low level C# adaptor program so it doesn't have access to the libraries most UI stuff would

**EDIT** I'm trying to do something like this

```
// On thread X   
Invoke((m_delegate)delegate(){
// Do something on main thread
});
```

Comment: What are you asking? How to implement thread-affine class with custom Invoke method? Please make the question clearer.

Comment: That code helps not one jot. What is your base class?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The classes I inherit from and implement are all custom, and this is a quite low level in the program chain. I'm trying to run a segment of code from a secondary thread on the main thread, see code example.

Comment: One obvious solution is to give these classes a reference to an object that can call Invoke. Can you do that?

Comment: Which thread are you expecting the delegate to get executed on?

Comment: @BrianGideon main thread

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I just noticed it already has a reference to System.Windows.Forms as Invoke is from that shouldn't VS2010 at least give me the option to "Resolve" by 'using' the right collection?

Comment: @Brent No I mean that your object could call `Invoke` on an object that implements `Invoke`. For example, its parent control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx) delegate  with an anonymous method, that is passed in an object to the right thread, and then executed. 
Works great and I find this code pretty sexy.

Answer (score 1):

it's hard to tell from the little you told about your code but maybe you can use [System.Threading.SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) to do the stuff you want.

**You just have to capture the context in your UI-thread** (for example by constructing your object there) and simulate `Control.Invoke` with [SynchronizationContext.Post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.post.aspx):

```
class MyObj
{
   SynchronizationContext _context;

   // please Note: construct the Objects in your main/ui thread to caputure the
   // right context
   public MyObj()
   {
     CaptureCurrentContext();
   }

   // or call this from your main/UI thread
   public void CaptureCurrentContext()
   {
      _context = SynchronizationContext.Current;
   }

   public void MyInvoke(Action a)
   {
       _context.Post((SendOrPostCallback)(_ => a()), null);
   }
}
```

BTW: here is a very good [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949789/using-synchronizationcontext-for-sending-events-back-to-the-ui-for-winforms-or-wp/2050346#2050346) to allmost the same question: [Using SynchronizationContext for sending ...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1949789/76051)

Comment: Beware that this won't work unless the constructor is called from the main thread.